# Error: Constant expression required, while declaring the array, like a[n]

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Here, constant expression is required, means can we not take firstly the input of n and then declare the array like int a[n].

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int n;
    scanf("\n Enter the no. of elements of the array. %d", n);
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("\n Enter the elements of the array. %d", &a[i]);
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
        printf(" %d", a[j]);
    return 0;
}
```

Please also tell me is it a dynamic memory allocation. If yes, then how is it different from new. As both new also allocates memory at runtime and this also.

Comment: You keep asing about "dynamic allocation". The C spec doesn't use that term. In C there is *static* storage duration, *automatic* storage duration, and *allocated* storage duration.  In your code `a` and `n` are automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not valid C90, but valid C99.

Variable-length arrays are not considered *dynamic memory allocation* since this term is used to refer to heap-based allocators (such as `malloc()`). But they are dynamic in the sense that the allocated size can only be calculated at execution time.

Comment: But, in int A[n], also the size is declared at run time. So, what we need to say it finally, that it is dynamically located or not?

Comment: What I've said in the answer. Strictly, it is indeed dynamically allocated, but no one would refer to VLAs as "dynamic allocated memory".

Comment: @Alek, strictly it depends on your definition of "dynamic" :)

Answer (score -3):

a[n] , in this case you should try to replace n with some value for eg :-a[100]
hope this will resolve your error .
good luck.